# Uniform plane waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

In uniform plane wave theory we will arrive at a situation that  considering TEM wave travelling in Z direction with electric field having only x component and magnetic field having only y component.
Divergence of E ,I.e electric field is zeo for source free region.
Which implies partial derivatives of Ey w.r.t  y and Ez w.r.t z  is equal to zero.
Finally we have  partial derivative of Ex w.r.t x also zero.
Explain all components of E becomes zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divergence is $div(E)=\partial E_x/\partial x + \partial E_y/\partial y + \partial E_z/\partial z = 0$.
For your plane wave you consider $E_y=E_z=0$, so $\partial E_x/\partial x=0$, to which a finite value of $E_x$ is a valid solution, as long as it does not vary with $x$. The partial derivatives do not apply in other directions, so for example the value of $E_x$ can vary with $z$, as long as all the derivatives satisfy the $Curl(E)=(1/c^2)\partial B/\partial t$.
As an example, $E_x =E_{xo}sin(kz)$ where $E_{xo}$ is a constant, satisfies $div(E)=0$.

Comment: Thank sir for ur explanation. If Ex is constant, Ey and Ez are equal to zero refers the condition for uniform plane wave or TEM.

Comment: In the explanation given by you we have Ex=finite value, Ey=0,Ez=0. Then my question is what it speaks about uniform plane waves?